# Replace Component with a Panel with BoxLayout (Y_AXIS) containing the component itself and my custom panel

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, boxlayout

this is my first question on this portal, do not judge strictly.

So. I am making a panel with the "Find and Replace" function. The idea is to pass an object of type JTextComponent to the constructor. And when calling the setVisible () override method in the JPanel, the text component should be replaced by the JPanel with the vertical BoxLayot layout manager containing my panel and the text component itself.
And it should look like this

[image: example]

The problem is that right now there are two components inside the scroll pane, and if I add this to the parent of the scroll pane, everything breaks.

[image: example_problem]
**My panel class**

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.JTextComponent;
import java.awt.*;

public class JPanelFindReplaceMin extends JPanel {

    private JLabel jLabelFind;
    private JCheckBox jCheckBoxCase;
    private JCheckBox jCheckBoxLoop;
    private JButton jButtonUp;
    private JButton jButtonDown;
    private JButton jButtonClose;
    private JTextField jTextFieldFind;
    private JTextComponent parentComponent;
    public JPanel replacePanel;

    public JPanelFindReplaceMin(JTextComponent parent) {
        this.parentComponent = parent;
        setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());
        jTextFieldFind = new JTextField();
        jLabelFind = new JLabel();
        jCheckBoxCase = new JCheckBox();
        jCheckBoxLoop = new JCheckBox();
        jButtonUp = new JButton();
        jButtonClose = new JButton();
        jButtonDown = new JButton();
        jButtonUp.setText("U");
        jButtonDown.setText("D");
        jButtonClose.setText("C");
        jLabelFind.setText("Find");
         jCheckBoxCase.setText("Case");
        jCheckBoxLoop.setText("Loop");
        this.setLayout(getCustomLayout());
    }


    @Override
    public void setVisible(boolean aFlag) {
        super.setVisible(aFlag);
        if (aFlag) {
            replacePanel = new JPanel();
            parentComponent.getParent().add(replacePanel);
            replacePanel.add(parentComponent);
            replacePanel.add(this);
            BoxLayout boxLayout = new BoxLayout(replacePanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);
            replacePanel.setLayout(boxLayout);
        }
    }

    private GroupLayout getCustomLayout() { // исправить(сделать универсальным)
        GroupLayout customPanelLayout = new GroupLayout(this);

            customPanelLayout.setHorizontalGroup(customPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(customPanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGap(6, 6, 6)
                            .addComponent(jLabelFind)
                            .addGap(2, 2, 2)
                            .addComponent(jTextFieldFind, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 171, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addPreferredGap(LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                            .addComponent(jCheckBoxCase)
                            .addPreferredGap(LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                            .addComponent(jCheckBoxLoop)
                            .addPreferredGap(LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                            .addComponent(jButtonDown, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 40, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addPreferredGap(LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                            .addComponent(jButtonUp, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 40, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addPreferredGap(LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(jButtonClose, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 40, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    )
            );
            customPanelLayout.setVerticalGroup(customPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, customPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                            .addComponent(jTextFieldFind, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(jLabelFind)
                            .addComponent(jCheckBoxCase)
                            .addComponent(jCheckBoxLoop)
                            .addComponent(jButtonDown, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 23, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(jButtonUp, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 23, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(jButtonClose, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 23, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            );
        jCheckBoxCase.setMargin(new Insets(2, 0, 2, 0));
        return customPanelLayout;
    }
}
```

**Main Class**

```
import javax.swing.*;
public class StartMin extends JFrame {
    private JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private JScrollPane jScrollPane2;
    private JTextArea jTextArea1;
    private JButton openF;
    private JTextArea parent;
    public StartMin() {
        initComponents();
    }
    private void initComponents() {
        jScrollPane2 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jTextArea1 = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        parent = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
        openF = new javax.swing.JButton();
        setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(700, 799));
        jTextArea1.setColumns(20);
        jTextArea1.setRows(5);
        jScrollPane2.setViewportView(jTextArea1);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        getContentPane().setLayout(new javax.swing.BoxLayout(getContentPane(), javax.swing.BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        parent.setColumns(20);
        parent.setRows(5);
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(parent);
        getContentPane().add(jScrollPane1);
        openF.setText("F");
        openF.addActionListener(this::openFActionPerformed);
        getContentPane().add(openF);
        pack();
    }
    private void openFActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        JPanel jPanel =  new JPanelFindReplaceMin(parent);
        jPanel.setVisible(true);
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            for (UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Windows".equals(info.getName())) {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ignored) {}
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> new StartMin().setVisible(true));
    }
}
```

[How it should look in the final](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tSfI9.gif)
The disadvantage of the example above is that my JPanel changes the specific Layout of the parent of the Text Area, and I need to achieve universality

Comment: 1) Use a `CardLayout` to swap between components or containers. 2) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [mre].

Comment: mre as advised is essential. Are you getting any exceptions?  It seems that `parentComponent` is added both to its parent as well as to `replacePanel`

Comment: Ready. I'm more interested in how to replace any JTextComponent with a conditional Jpanel, so that it has the same size, it is built into the same any Layout Manager as the JTextComponent.

Comment: Your main panel could use a `BorderLayout`. Your text pane would be added to the `BorderLayout.CENTER`. The find/replace dialog would be added to the `BorderLayout.PAGE_END`. You then make the find/replace panel visible as required. This way there is no need to continually swap panels.